# Azure FrontDoor: how to set up backendPool with multiple instance inside?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-front-door

I started Infrastructure as Code with ARM Template and previously all my deployment was made with Powershell. Hope you can help me to fix this issue.

I would like to deploy {2 app services + Azure FrontDoor]. In FrontDoor-Backendpool I want to define the 2 appservices. Below my code:

```
{
"$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
    "location": {
        "type": "array",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "array of region"
        },
        "defaultValue": [
            "centralus",
            "eastus"
        ]
    },
    "Stage": {
        "type": "string",
        "metadata": {
            "description": "Stage dev, prod"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
            "Dev",
            "Prod"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "Dev"
    }
},
"functions": [],
"variables": {
    "appServicePlanName": "[concat('AppServicePlan-', parameters('Stage'),'-')]",
    "appServiceName": "[concat('AppService-', parameters('Stage'), '-')]",
    "frontDoorName": "[concat('FrontDoor-', parameters('Stage'), uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]"
},
"resources": [
    { // App Service Plan
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/serverfarms",
        "name": "[concat(variables('appServicePlanName'),parameters('location')[copyIndex()])]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",
        "copy": {
            "count": "[length(parameters('location'))]",
            "name": "copy multiple"
        },
        "location": "[parameters('location')[copyIndex()]]",
        "sku": {
            "name": "F1",
            "capacity": 1
        },
        "tags": {
            "cost": "[parameters('Stage')]"
        },
        "properties": {
            "name": "[concat(variables('appServicePlanName'),parameters('location')[copyIndex()])]"
        }
    },
    { // App Services
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
        "name": "[concat(variables('appServiceName'), parameters('location')[copyIndex()])]",
        "apiVersion": "2018-11-01",
        "copy": {
            "name": "Copy website",
            "count": "[length(parameters('location'))]"
        },
        "location": "[parameters('location')[copyIndex()]]",
        "tags": {
            "cost": "[parameters('Stage')]"
        },
        "dependsOn": [
            "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', concat(variables('appServicePlanName'),parameters('location')[copyIndex()]))]"
        ],
        "properties": {
            "name": "[concat(variables('appServiceName'), parameters('location')[copyIndex()])]",
            "serverFarmId": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Web/serverfarms', concat(variables('appServicePlanName'),parameters('location')[copyIndex()]))]"
        }
    },
    { // Front Door
        "type": "Microsoft.Network/frontDoors",
        "apiVersion": "2020-05-01",
        "name": "[variables('frontDoorName')]",
        "location": "global",
        "properties": {
            "routingRules": [
                {
                    "name": "routingRule1",
                    "properties": {
                        "frontendEndpoints": [
                            {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/frontendEndpoints', variables('frontDoorName'), 'frontendEndpoint1')]"
                            }
                        ],
                        "acceptedProtocols": [
                            "Http",
                            "Https"
                        ],
                        "patternsToMatch": [
                            "/*"
                        ],
                        "routeConfiguration": {
                            "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.FrontDoor.Models.FrontdoorForwardingConfiguration",
                            "forwardingProtocol": "MatchRequest",
                            "backendPool": {
                                "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/backendPools', variables('frontDoorName'), 'backendPool1')]"
                            }
                        },
                        "enabledState": "Enabled"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "healthProbeSettings": [
                {
                    "name": "healthProbeSettings1",
                    "properties": {
                        "path": "/",
                        "protocol": "Http",
                        "intervalInSeconds": 120
                    }
                }
            ],
            "loadBalancingSettings": [
                {
                    "name": "loadBalancingSettings1",
                    "properties": {
                        "sampleSize": 4,
                        "successfulSamplesRequired": 2
                    }
                }
            ],
            "backendPools": [
                {
                    "id": "backendPool1",
                    "name": "backendPool1",
                    "properties": {
                        "copy": [
                            {
                                "name": "backends",
                                "count": "[length(parameters('location'))]",
                                "input": {
                                    "address": "[concat(variables('appServiceName'), parameters('location')[copyIndex()], '.azurewebsites.net') ]",
                                    "httpPort": 80,
                                    "httpsPort": 443,
                                    "weight": 50,
                                    "priority": 1,
                                    "enabledState": "Enabled"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "loadBalancingSettings": {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/loadBalancingSettings', variables('frontDoorName'), 'loadBalancingSettings1')]"
                        },
                        "healthProbeSettings": {
                            "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/frontDoors/healthProbeSettings', variables('frontDoorName'), 'healthProbeSettings1')]"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "frontendEndpoints": [
                {
                    "name": "frontendEndpoint1",
                    "properties": {
                        "hostName": "[concat(variables('frontDoorName'), '.azurefd.net')]",
                        "sessionAffinityEnabledState": "Enabled"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "enabledState": "Enabled"
        }
    }

],
"outputs": {}
```

}

As you can see i iterate on paramater *location* to create my AppService Plan and AppService and it worked well. So I thought to do same for BackEndpool.

Here part of code which break my head

```
address": "[concat(variables('appServiceName'), parameters('location')[copyIndex()], '.azurewebsites.net') ]",
```

Something is wrong inside but I have no idea why.
Error retuned is:
*Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template language expression evaluation
failed: 'The template language function 'copyIndex' has an invalid argument. The provided copy name '' doesn't exist in the resource.
Please see https://aka.ms/arm-copy for usage details.'. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template-expressions for usage details.*

I take my inspiration from official MS documentation [link from MS](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/101-front-door-create-multiple-backends/azuredeploy.json)
Any idea on how I can fix it ?
Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the `copy` name property in the call to `copyIndex` in the `backendPools` part. That is why is says "The provided copy name **''** doesn't exist". The property copy is treated a little differently than the resource copy.

"The loopName property enables you to specify whether copyIndex is referring to a resource iteration or property iteration. If no value is provided for loopName, the current resource type iteration is used. Provide a value for loopName when iterating on a property."
Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-numeric#copyindex

```
parameters('location')[copyIndex('backends')]
```